# Volatile is not preventing a variable from being optimized

Tags: c, memory, volatile

As I know, "volatile" keyword is used to prevent compiler to optimize an unused variable. I am working with an STM32 board and I declare and initialise a variable as follows;

```
volatile uint32_t errorCallbackCounter = 24 ;
```

And never use it again.

While debugging, this variable is not seen. I am checking it with STMStudio( a real time variable watcher ) and when I want to import variables, the adress of `errorCallbackCounter` is seen as 0x0.

But when I use it in anywhere, it becomes visible.

So volatile keyword is not doing its job or -more probably- I know something wrong about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variables that are never used can be dropped by the linker**

The `volatile` keyword affects the code that accesses the variable, preventing the *access* from being rearranged or dropped by the compiler. The line above is a variable *definition* with an initializer, that doesn't count as an access, it gets arranged before `main()` starts. But if it isn't referenced by *accessible* program code, isn't *accessed* at all, the linker thinks that it's safe to remove it, no one would notice.

You can however mark the variable as "it's needed no matter what" with

```
__attribute__((used))
```

placed at the end of the definition. This works with `gcc`, other compilers might have another directive for it. There is also a linker option that I can't recall right now to include all unused data sections in the executable.

Comment: thank you, this answered my question pretty much. If you'll have time could you please look the example of me on the comment section of the above answer(to check whether I get it right or not) .

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` means the system will load this variable from memory each time it is accessed.
The compiler is not allowed to store the data directly into an register.

> The volatile keyword prevents the compiler from performing optimization on code involving volatile objects, thus ensuring that each volatile variable assignment and read has a corresponding memory access. Without the volatile keyword, the compiler knows a variable does not need to be reread from memory at each use, because there should not be any writes to its memory location from any other thread or process.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer so my understanding about volatile was a little bit wrong than. So, do you know any solutions to my problem or do you know why? Is it some other optimization issue?

Comment: I don't know why you want to have a variable that is never used, but I think if you read it at least one time in your code the compiler will create it.

Comment: I don't need it for any certain purpose, I just got curious about it. So `volatile` will make a difference in a scenario like this then, `int a=5; while(a){}` may result in an **absolute** infinite loop if it is optimized. On the other hand, the processor will check all the time the value of variable `a` in the case of `volatile int a=5; while(a){}`. Am i correct now? Thanks.

Comment: @muyustan Yes, the first one would wait forever, the latter one would wait just until `a` becomes `0` somehow, e.g. changed by a signal or interrupt handler.